# cannot convert from 'cv::Mat *' to 'const cv::Mat'

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to pass an Image from `main()` to another function. And, then I am trying to upload that image to the GPU. But I am getting an error while doing so.

**Important:** I have to take care of computational time.

**My code:**

```
void gpuProcessing( const Mat& cpuBayerImage)
{
    //Loading image to the GPU
    cv::gpu::GpuMat gpuBayerImage;
    gpuBayerImage.upload(cpuRawBayerImage);
}

int main ()
{
    ---
    Mat cpuBayerImage(size[1], size[0], CV_16UC1, imageData);
    gpuProcessing( &cpuBayerImage);
}
```

**Error:**

```
error C2664: 'gpuProcessing' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cv::Mat *' to 'const cv::Mat &'
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'cv::Mat *' to 'const cv::Mat'
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to pass an Image from main() to another function by reference

You're actually passing it by pointer. Change:

```
gpuProcessing( &cpuBayerImage );
```

to:

```
gpuProcessing( cpuBayerImage );
```

I'm guessing `cpuBayerImage` is just a `cv::Mat`. The function `gpuProcessing` takes a reference to const `cv::Mat`, but instead you are taking the address of it and giving it a pointer to `cv::Mat`. A pointer and a reference, despite being similar concepts, are not convertible to each other.

Comment: yes, that will work but then it will copy the whole data which will be costly in terms of computational time.

Comment: `cv::Mat` is only the header (information about image size, datatype and WHERE the data is placed) so passing a `cv::Mat` by value only copies the header, which is quite efficient. Pixel data isn't copied until you use `.copyTo()` or `.clone()` methods. So you won't see much performance problems, and most OpenCV functions will take the Mats by reference anyway.

Comment: @skm No it won't copy - the function takes it by *reference*, not by value.

Comment: @Barry: yes, I have read about it in a post at SO but I am a but skeptical about it. I am afraid that it will increase the computational time. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: write `void gpuProcessing( Mat * cpuBayerImage)` instead (and dereference on use), but there won't be any improvement and it won't be intuitive for people who are experienced with opencv

Comment: @skm Yeah, you should read about it in a book on C++. If you're skeptical about how core language features work, that's going to limit the quality of the code you write.

Comment: Ok, I made a mistake. Instead of calling  `gpuProcessing( cpuBayerImage );` , I called `gpuProcessing( &cpuBayerImage );` in the ``main()`. Thanks :)

Comment: @skm This is also easy to verify with a [toy example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ec34b8b08223342)